# In Rails how to combine values from three drop downs into a single record for a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am building  RoR sitre , I have three dropdown list on a page. i.e. category, subcategory and rank. User can select  values  for all three  drop downs and click "add" button, then  by way of jQuery/javascript a row is created on the page as below. User can add upto 10 rows like that.

### Category Subcategory Rank

```
A        Sub-1A        1   

B        Sub-1B        2

B        Sub-1B        2
```

If user has choosen three combination as above , I want to post those three rows to the server and store them in my database model (which has category, subcategory and rank  fields) as three records. 
I do not need to post the dropdown selection  BUT the choosen combinations shown as rows.

This is part of the form, which has usual form fileds like  first name, last name, address etc.
Question is how to do I post this tabular data along with all other fields and access it my controller ?

Comment: I have found the  solution . I used the jQuery to add new rows and delete rows and  datatables jQuery plugin to sort and search and send AJAX request back to server.

Comment: You should add your solution as an "answer" for your question. This way if other people have the same problem and come looking for a solution - they find yours.