# Rails: Combine 3 select drop-downs to modify 1 attribute of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

So normally I use the `date_select` helper in my Rails applications in my Models' forms, but in the most recent application I was building, I needed to specify individual css id's for each drop down (month, day, year), and that isn't possible with `date_select`. So instead, I've been using `select_month`, `select_day`, and `select_year` helpers. Here's the problem: how do I get them to all describe one `datetime` record in my database?

(I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657902/in-rails-how-to-combine-values-from-three-drop-downs-into-a-single-record-for-a) by the way, but it looks pretty useless to me. Plus, I don't want to do some hacky jQuery stuff handling this.)

Here's what I have so far:

```
#default_time_for is just a helper method that returns the default time for the specified "period" of time (month,day,etc.)

<%= select_month(default_time_for(:month)) %>
<%= select_day(default_time_for(:day)) %> 
<%= select_year(default_time_for(:year), {:start_year => Time.now.year-18, :end_year => 1930}) %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd combine them on the server side:

```
require 'date'

def update
  date = Date.parse(params[:year] + params[:month] + params[:day])

  # Add to object and save
end
```

You can still do mass-assignment, assuming that `date` is the field you want to assign to, you could do the following:

```
def update
  date = Date.parse(params[:year] + params[:month] + params[:day])
  params = params.merge( { :user => { :date => date }})

  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(params)
    # save was good
  else
    # save was bad
  end
end
```

**Also make sure you're familiar and mitigated against the [security issued cased by Mass Assignment](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment) if you're going to use the above code.**

Comment: The reason I'm hesitant to do this is because I have a lot of fields, and I was just going to mass-assign them.... is there any way to keep the rest of the attributes mass-assignable? (I want to do `User.save(params[:user])` for the rest of the attributes if possible)